# WebDriverIO - Error switching to iframe in Salesforce application (WDIO v7, Chrome Browser v96.0.4664.45)

Tags: javascript, iframe, salesforce-lightning, wdio-v6

We had written a test using WDIO, which was executing as expected on Chrome browser v95.X.
With Chrome browser upgrading to v96.0.4664.45, the test has started failing throwing an error. Detail as below:

**Line:** await browser.switchToFrame(await $('(//iframe)[1]'));

**Expected:** Control to be transferred to iFrame

**Actual:** Error: no such frame

Upon investigating we found that if we try to get iFrame web element and print few of it's attribute values in console, it is correctly logged and matches with developer console values. But on next line when we try to switch to iFrame, we encounter above error.

This piece was working as expected last week on Chrome browser v95.X.

Our web application is based on salesforce lightning technology.

Did anyone face similar kind of issue? Any resolution?

Comment: I don't have much to add other than: yes I have exactly the same problem, also since roughly chrome v95 (still now on v100), and I'm on wdio v6.10.11. If you figured it out or happen to figure it out in the future, I'd love an update :)